# Variable unknown when not initialized in the declaration

Tags: rascal

I ran into this today, and I was wondering if something is going wrong here.

```
module example

public rel[str file, AstNode namespace] relFileNamespace;
public void InitGlobals()
{
    relFileNamespace = {};
}
```

Then in the console:

```
rascal>import example;
ok

rascal>InitGlobals();
ok

rascal>relFileNamespace
|stdin:///|(0,13,<1,0>,<1,13>): Undeclared variable, function or constructor: relFileNamespace
```

If I declare it like this it does work.

```
public rel[str file, AstNode namespace] relFileNamespace = {};
```

So the question is, **why does it have to be initialized in the declaration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Rascal does not allow uninitialized variables at all, but it should complain about "uninitialized" in that case, not "undeclared"
- It is not finding your variable. Could you try adding "example::" before dereferencing?

Comment: Indeed, copy paste mistake. Updated it.

Comment: If rascal does not allow it, maybe it should be a syntax error then?

Comment: Adding "example::" does not give different results.